# Error when trying to delete a folder in a makefile

Tags: makefile, mingw, gnu-make

Hello i encountered an error when trying to delete a folder. In my makefile i wrote:

```
cmd //c del bin/debug/res
```

and it gave me the error:

```
'es' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

I'm new to makefiles.

Thanks

Comment: Can you execute this same command from the command line? If not fix the errors until it works on the command line, and modify your Makefile accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`DEL` is for deleting files. To delete folders use `RMDIR`.

Note that you can only delete folders that are empty, so if the folder is not empty you should use `DEL /S` followed by `RMDIR /S`. The `/S` flag is to also handle subfolders.